# master: Error: Could not find or load main class master.log

Tags: hadoop

I have some problems. When I run the command `start-dfs.sh`, I get this error:

```
master: Error: Could not find or load main class master.log”.
The hadoop version is 2.7.2 and 2.6.4.
OS is centos 7.

Error: Could not find or load main class master.log
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 14631
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's your question? You only show us an error message. Please look through this [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Seems like you have misconfigured one of the XML files. Perhaps hdfs-site. Please [edit] your question to include it and any other steps you followed to get to this error

Answer (score 0):

- I had faced a similar issue and would like to share the thing that
  worked for me. There seems to be an issue related to the hostname. It
  had been changed due to some reason and I just cross-checked
  hostname(/etc/hostname) file, reverted it to the earlier name and
  just restarted my machine with 'init 6'(reboot command didn't work
  for me) and the issue was resolved. Hope this may help youin some
  way.